# importlib has some questions result to my anaconda and jupternotebook even pip didn't work

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3, python-importlib

when i opened jupternotebook in anaconda3, it showed that:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\cwp.py", line 9, in <module>
    from menuinst.knownfolders import FOLDERID, get_folder_path, PathNotFoundException
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .win32 import Menu, ShortCut
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\win32.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 2, in <module>
    import imp, sys, os
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 857, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 525, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

then i guessed it may be importlib's error but when i wanted to check the version of this package, i found i can't use the command below

```
PS C:\Users\Jayus> python -m pip list
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 15, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 857, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 525, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

```
PS C:\Users\Jayus> pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\util.py", line 9, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 857, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 525, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

it clearly is the importlib's error but how can i fix it? I have tried install it in anaconda3 and the pycharm, but i can not even open it, when i use the command below, error again.

```
PS C:\Users\Jayus> conda activate base
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\_vendor\five.py", line 47, in <module>
    reload = reload                         # noqa
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 151, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._vendor.auxlib.entity import EntityEncoder
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\entity.py", line 253, in <module>
    from .collection import AttrDict, frozendict, make_immutable
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\collection.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .compat import isiterable, iteritems, odict, text_type
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\compat.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._vendor.five import WhateverIO as StringIO, with_metaclass
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\_vendor\five.py", line 49, in <module>
    from imp import reload                  # noqa
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 857, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 525, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

> base is my env name, and it is the default env

by the way, i can not open anaconda3 powershell prompt and the navigator, that is the result.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\_vendor\five.py", line 47, in <module>
    reload = reload                         # noqa
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 139, in main
    from ..activate import main as activator_main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ._vendor.auxlib.compat import Utf8NamedTemporaryFile
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\compat.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._vendor.five import WhateverIO as StringIO, with_metaclass
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\_vendor\five.py", line 49, in <module>
    from imp import reload                  # noqa
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 857, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 525, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\_vendor\five.py", line 47, in <module>
    reload = reload                         # noqa
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 147, in main
    init_loggers()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 56, in init_loggers
    from ..gateways.logging import initialize_logging, set_verbosity
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\logging.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..common.io import attach_stderr_handler
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .._vendor.auxlib.logz import NullHandler
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\logz.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .compat import text_type
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\compat.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._vendor.five import WhateverIO as StringIO, with_metaclass
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\_vendor\five.py", line 49, in <module>
    from imp import reload                  # noqa
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 857, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 525, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
Invoke-Expression : 无法将参数绑定到参数“Command”，因为该参数为空字符串。
所在位置 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:101 字符: 36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression]，ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand
```

i can still use the python command,but that's it,that's all i can use maybe. thank you for all if you can help me.

Comment: my python version is 3.7.6

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, maybe not solve, i just reinstalled it....